# Pegar determinado parte do html vindo de outra pagina com javascript

Tags: javascript

Ola a todos pessoal queria pegar uma área especifica do que esta vindo da outra pagina por exemplo o que vem da outra pagina eu pegar a div com id tal como faria isso com meu script?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        // Função responsável por atualizar as frases
        function atualizar()
        {
            // Fazendo requisição AJAX

$('#mensagensinbox').load("functions/atumensainbox.php?id_log_ass=<?php echo $id_log_ass;  ?>");


        }
        // Definindo intervalo que a função será chamada
        setInterval("atualizar()", 10000);
        // Quando carregar a página
        $(function() {
            // Faz a primeira atualização
            atualizar();
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite Gezer, é necessário você conhecer os identificadores que você deseja pegar dentro do `html` retornado pelo `$.load()`.

Note que o `html` retornado pelo `$.load()` será carregado no `div` **#mensagensinbox**.

Dai basta que você encontre os identificadores dentro de **#mensagensinbox**.

Imagine que o `html` da página que foi carregada retorne:

```
<!-- muitos outras tags acima -->
<div class="mensagens">
   <span class="titulo"> Boa noite</span>
   <p class="mensagem">Oi, como vai você, queria te desejar boa noite.</p>
</div>
<!-- muitas outras tags abaixo -->
```

Para você pegar um conteúdio específico dentro de todas essas tags que foram retornadas, ficaria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
var mensagens = $("#mensagensinbox").find(".mensagens");
```

Por fim, se você der um `console.log(mensagens[0]);` você vai perceber o seguinte `html`.

```
<div class="mensagens">
<span class="titulo"> Boa noite</span>
<p class="mensagem">Oi, como vai você, queria te desejar boa noite.</p>
</div>
```

Para concluir, dentro de todo o conteúdo retornado na função **load**, você só pegou a `div` que contém a *class* **.mensagens**.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Agora que lembrei rsrs o load dentro dele eu posso colocar a id da div por exemplo   $('#mensagensinbox').load("functions/atumensainbox.php?id_log_ass=<?php echo $id_log_ass;  ?>    #essadiv");

Comment: Pode sim, mas acredito que da mesma forma, o retorno do conteúdo do `load` continuará sendo todo o conteúdo da página *functions/atumensainbox.php*.
Você deve pegar o conteúdo depois do retorno. **UPDATE** - Se utilizar o **#** você só pega o conteúdo dessa identificador.

Comment: resolveu ele so pegou a div que queria mesmo ficou top agora.

Comment: Interessante...

Comment: por exemplo agora ficou assim $('#mensagensinbox').load("functions/atumensainbox.php?id_log_ass=<?php echo $id_log_ass;  ?> #mensagens"); chamando outra parte
$('#mensagensvalinbox').load("functions/atumensainbox.php?id_log_ass=<?php echo $id_log_ass;?> #totalmensagens");